# Intuition about the Bernstein polynomials proof of the Weierstrass approximation theorem

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, polynomials, uniform-convergence

The Weierstrass approximation theorem can be stated as follows:

> Let $f\in C([a,b])$. There exists a sequence $(p_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ of polynomials in $[a,b]$ such that $(p_n)$ converges uniformly to $f$.

One approach to prove this theorem is to notice that we just need to prove this for $[a,b]=[0,1]$ and then consider the Bernstein polynomials:

$$B_n(f)(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n f\left(\dfrac{k}{n}\right)\binom{n}{k}x^k(1-x)^{n-k},$$

and then prove that $(B_n(f))$ converges uniformly to $f$. The proof then indeed shows this convergence.

My question here is regarding intuition. This is the kind of thing that I wonder how could anyone think of defining those polynomials so that they converge to $f$.

So: what is the intuition behind the Bernstein polynomials? Considering that we want to find a sequence of polynomials which converge uniformly to a continuous function, how could we ever think about defining those polynomials? Is there some intuition here?

Comment: The best intuition/construction is probabilistic: $$B_n(f)(x) = E\left(f\left(\frac{B(n,x)}n\right)\right)$$ for a binomial $B(n,x)$ and by LLN, $n^{-1}B(n,x)\to x$ a.s.

Comment: @A.S., [Bernstein's original proof](http://nonagon.org/ExLibris/bernsteins-demonstration-du-theoreme-de-Weierstrass) was probabilistic.

Comment: Another approach may be the convex hull property of Bernstein polynomials. The polygon given by $f(\frac{k}{n})$ is close to the polynomial in a very "nice" sense. See for example:http://web.mit.edu/hyperbook/Patrikalakis-Maekawa-Cho/node12.html (although this example is 2D instead of 1D). This is why Bernstein polynomials are heavily used in CAD as part of Bezier curves and NURBS.

Answer (score 2):

The sum of the coefficients ${n\choose k}x^k(1-x)^{n-k}$ is equal $1.$ For $ x$ close to ${k\over n}$ the coefficient ${n\choose k}x^k(1-x)^{n-k}$ is the largest.