# What was the Original Need/Purpose for Defining Bernstein Polynomials?

Tags: polynomials

**I am interested in learning about the reason as to why Bernstein Polynomials were first defined.**

After consulting the Wikipedia article on Bernstein Polynomials, these appear to be polynomials that follow a certain pattern:

[image]

**My Question:** Does anyone know what lead to the Bernstein Polynomials being defined - after all, why were they defined using a specific basis function? I have heard that the Bernstein Polynomials were first used to prove the Stone-Weierstrass Approximation Theorem - was Sergei Bernstein trying to find a new way to prove the Stone-Weierstrass Theorem and as a result developed the Bernstein Polynomials?

Thanks!

**References:**

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein_polynomial
- https://nonagon.org/ExLibris/bernstein-proves-weierstrass

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1696961/intuition-about-the-bernstein-polynomials-proof-of-the-weierstrass-approximation